# The right side of all the text on my website is getting cut off

Tags: html, css, wordpress

The right side of all the text on my website is getting cut off. I try to inspect the element in Firebug and it's always

paragraph text, but since they all have different parent divs I'm not sure what to do in CSS to fix this. Here is some links to show you what is going on, maybe it will help. Please let me know what I should do.

Question Answered - thanks

Comment: where's the link to your site or relevant code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set width auto to class `.cross-sells h4, h5, h6, p`

below is the `CSS`

```
.cross-sells h4, h5, h6, p {
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Welcome George McKenzie :)

Comment: there is no relevant code or website link in the question or it has been edited. how @Kishori was able to answer???

Comment: Yes there was a link. :D

Answer (score 1):

Try to add "clear:both;" to #info_bar .
Also it's a good practice to use something like firebug to debug css.